# Finding a way to simplify complex queries on legacy application

Tags: design-patterns, database, orm, optimization

I am working with an existing application built on Rails 3.1/MySql with much of the work taking place in a JavaScript interface, although the actual platforms are not tremendously relevant here, except in that they give context.

The application is powerful, handles a reasonable amount of data and works well. As the number of customers using it and the complexity of the projects they create increases, however, we are starting to run into a few performance problems. As far as I can tell, the source of these problems is that the data represents a tree and it is very hard for ActiveRecord to deterministically know what data it should be retrieving.

My model has many relationships like this:

```
Project
   has_many Nodes
   has_many GlobalConditions

Node 
   has_one Parent
   has_many Nodes
   has_many WeightingFactors through NodeFactors
   has_many Tags through NodeTags

GlobalCondition
   has_many Nodes ( referenced by Id, rather than replicating tree )

WeightingFactor
   has_many Nodes through NodeFactors

Tag
   has_many Nodes through NodeTags
```

[image]

The whole system has something in the region of thirty types which optionally hang off one or many nodes in the tree.

My question is: What can I do to retrieve and construct this data faster?

Having worked a lot with .Net, if I was in a similar situation there, I would look at building up a Stored Procedure to pull everything out of the database in one go but I would prefer to keep my logic in the application and from what I can tell it would be hard to take the queried data and build ActiveRecord objects from it without losing their integrity, which would cause more problems than it solves.

It has also occurred to me that I could bunch the data up and send some of it across asynchronously, which would not improve performance but would improve the user perception of performance. However if sections of the data appeared after page load that could also be quite confusing.

I am wondering whether it would be a useful strategy to make everything aware of it's parent project, so that one could pull all the records for that project and then build up the relationships later, but given the ubiquity of complex trees in day to day programming life I wouldn't be surprised if there were some better design patterns or standard approaches to this type of situation that I am not well versed in.

Comment: [The last Rails 3.1 release was March 18, 2013](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/3/18/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-13-3-1-12-and-2-3-18-have-been-released/). The app was built on that, and it's already legacy?

Comment: @l0b0 Legacy code is simply code without unit tests.

Comment: You might want to change the title then, either to "[expletive] application" or the more descriptive "untested application".

Comment: @Eric & l0b0: that is just Michael Feather's definition (which is not bad, but not the only popular one). Other people call everything "legacy" which has gone under maintenance.

Comment: This code has reasonable test coverage here. I am using "legacy" to mean "has been running for a few years, features and components bolted on over time, written by different people most of whom are not me, still in constant use, not candidate for rewriting on a different platform or changing core libraries." Maybe "Legacy" isn't the term for that? Possibly "Production"?

Comment: @l0b0 the last Rails 3.1 release was March 18 2013, the first was 2011 and this was probably Rails 3.0 originally, so the platform version has been five years or so. 3.2 and 4.x are both newer but because of the open source development "lets pick some trendy libraries and depend on them even though they'll probably be deprecated next month" philosophy I haven't had time to get it migrated onto a current version.

Comment: @l0b0: It is better to compare when the *first* release of Rails 3.1 came out around August 30, 2011. And applications can become legacy in a few years.

Answer (score 1):

> whether it would be a useful strategy to make everything aware of it's parent project

That *is* a standard strategy. It is called "[denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)". Assumed

- your "project elements" never change the project they belong to
- your project's primary ID key will never change
- the additional memory needed for the IDs is no problem
- it actually solves your performance problems

you should apply it.

Another approach is trying to add some views to your database, encapsulating some complex JOIN operations (I assume your database is properly indexed so the JOIN itself won't slow down things more than necessary). I never used Rails by mayself, but AFAIK ActiveRecord will work on views. So for example by joining 2 tables of a parent-child relationship together, instead of having a first SELECT SQL to determine a set of parent objects, and a list of SELECT SQLs, each one for the set of child objects of a specific parent ID, you pull all your data from the joined view with just one select SQL. Of course, this will work best when you need the data in joined form and don't want to write changes back to your DB system.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful- the system I am working with is theoretically well designed but becoming impractical in real-world operation, so I think denormalisation may well be helpful. I will look into views- updates come in through a separate queue already, so read-only behaviours would not be a problem.